# Selenium RC in Hudson

Tags: c#, selenium, hudson, selenium-rc

is there a way to install selenium into hudson, and have it run a test via a .dll (c#)? all i can find so far is a html script.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The fix i've found for this, was to use gallio and push my compiled DLL throw its gallio.echo console.

hudson passes and fails the job based on the results from gallio.

Answer (score 1):

If your Selenium test are based on NUnit, you should be able to run them in Hudson. You can also utilize [Selenium Plugin](http://wiki.hudson-ci.org/display/HUDSON/Selenium+Plugin) for Hudson in this case.

Comment: Thanks i looked into that however i failed to get any connections through to it, it never saw any slaves, probably because i was running hudson and selenium on the same machine. the fix i found was to add a slave that started selenium, that way selenium was always running.